# Changing sheetId in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps

Is this possible? I know I can call .getSheetId(), but is there any way (programmatically or not) to change a sheet's ID?

Comment: why would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a copy of the sheet and rename it, it will have a new ID, other than that no, you can't name your own ID.